# Custom Listbox Items

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7

I just started my WP7 programming journey. I need to add 2 text lines as an item to the listbox.

What are my options?

I read about user control and some others. What is the easiest way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be based on the code that comes in the default project types.

Create a new "DataBound" application and you'll see that it shows multiple lines per item using a `DataTemplate` for the `ListBox.Item`.

**Update**
To retrieve the selected item, cast its datacontext to whatever the object is on the viewmodel.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use a stackpanel and add two textblock in my code to add into listbox. It works great. But how can I retrieve the items value?